# Editor being able to create tabs (quicktabs style) inside CKeditor

Tags: wysiwyg, blocks

I am trying to provide a way for our content editor to create tabbed content inside the ckeditor, but I am a bit stuck.

Do you guys, have any ideas how to do that ?

**What I have already tried ?**

Quicktabs module and blocks for specific page...but this method requires too much administrator rights for the editor ( quicktabs and blocks access ).

Oleg

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but this module will do it for you. I've been using it for a while now.

https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_tabber

Comment: Well spotted :)

Answer (score 2):

Just make Body field multivalue. Look for this setting:

[image: Number of values]

Then it will be up to your tpl file and your theme's javascripts to style it as tabs.

---

You can also try to use [Field Collection Tab formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_tabs), it looks like what you want:

[image: Image from module's page]

I don't know this module personally, I always did things like that on my own, but looks simple enough.

Comment: Thanks Molot, I was thinking for something similar,the problem (as always) is the time... Still do you know something that will work more like "out of  the box" ? :)

Comment: @OlegVidenov not really. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Molot, the Fiel collection tab formatter adds level of flexibility. I also found. https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_tools_plus
Regards